# Package org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf empty

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, hadoop, protocol-buffers

I just get the last stable Hadoop version (2.4) and followed [this](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment) instruction to import it into Eclipse.

However, I've having several build errors of `cannot be resolved to a type` in the test src folder. As an example:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.TestProtos.EchoRequestProto;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.TestProtos.EchoResponseProto;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.TestProtos.EmptyRequestProto;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.TestProtos.EmptyResponseProto;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.TestRpcServiceProtos.TestProtobufRpcProto;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.TestRpcServiceProtos.TestProtobufRpc2Proto;
```

Eclipse cannot find any of these classes, simply because **org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf** package is empty. Am I doing something wrong? Missing some configuration step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find any Java files under these packages in the hadoop source code repository. Java files under this packages will be generated by protoc compiler

When you execute maven install `mvn install -DskipTests` protoc compiler will generate the corresponding .java files

For Setting up hadoop build environment, refer the following link

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute

Install native libraries 
Install protobuf etc. Refer above link for detailed information

Once you successfully execute the command `mvn install -DskipTests` you can see the java files under protobuf packages

Comment: Thanks, everything compiling. One follow up question: is it possible to run Hadoop 2.4 locally from Eclipse? Or because YARN it is not possible anymore? I googling for `Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration...` without success, because most of the questions are still for Hadoop 1.x

Comment: Hi,

I am also getting the same errors missing the same packegaes and I ran mvn install -DskipTests without any errors but the packages are still missing.

Any ideas? 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try cd to path "/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/test/proto" and execute following command:`protoc --java_out=../java *.proto`. Please note that you should have protocol buffers (A Google project) properly installed, which you may simply get from [github](https://github.com/google/protobuf).

Answer (score 0):

The protobuf related java files are in your `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java`, where `project.build.directory` in my condition is `<module_path>/target`.
So the full path is `<module_path>/target/generated-sources/java`. I use Intellij idea, after I marking the aforementioned full path as sources root, everything is ok. In your contition, you can try to mark `<your_hadoop_project_root_path>/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/generated-sources/java` as sources root.